# What is the size of a single sign in .txt file?

Tags: size, storage, computer-science, usb-drive

For some reason I need to create and save a 512 MB .txt file on my 512MB pendrive. The file has to be made of alternaning zeroes and ones.

I'm gonna make a program that makes n such signs, but I need to know how big n must be to make this file 512 MB big. How to determine it? What is the size of single "1" or "0"? And how big is just "existance" of the file.

Comment: The reason is that I want to make some experiments with pendrive and then check if data is corrupt in easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how big the characters "1" and "0" are, the answer is 1 byte, assuming ASCII OR UTF-8 encoding. So if you want exactly 512 MB you will need 512 * 1024 * 1024 bytes. But keep in mind that drives aren't exactly the size they claim to be (MB vs MiB) and each drive is slightly different, so keep this in mind.

Comment: :) Thanks! However I just made a "test file" containing three symbols and when I saved it, closed, right clicked file and clicked "properties", size was indeed 3, but "size on a disk" was 4KB (4096B). Why? What is "size on disk"? And how should I consider it in my plan?

Comment: Okay... I just checked what is "size on disk". But it does not depend so linearly on number of characters in file.

Comment: Anyway, you exactly answered my question. You're great. :)

Comment: You want "Size" which gives the actual file size in bytes. "Size on disk" is a multiple of cluster/block size.